tRPC integration issue with the client-side
the thing is i dont have one single specific problem but several stuff xD,im working with electron and react, and my backend dev is using tRPC for the api , now that i'm integrating im kinda confsued how to really pull it out w also link it with global state ? (im using redux toolkit) w also when i came to use the pending and rejected states of async thunks i found that trpc already provides them as shown in the pic below , also GET requests in trpc are perfomed with this syntax :
trpc.route.secondaryRoute.function.useQuery(req) 

for example which is using hooks so i gotta call it inside a functional component so if u could provide me some good example and explanation for how i can i do it i really would be thankful cuz i think i will end up some really messy code lol


You shouldn't.
That data is already in a global cache - the TanStack Query cache.
There is no value copying that state over into Redux. You just duplicate data, clog up memory and lose out on most benefits of the global state solution TRPC already comes with. It will go out of sync and be stale in multiple places.
Instead, read up on TanStack Query and learn how to utilize their state management to it's fullest. You can still use Redux for local application state, but for API data you already have chosen a cache manager, you don't need two of those.

But when i use Tanstack query for fetching and other stuff, how can i keep my data in sync ? Do i apply props drilling? Cuz as i found in their docs they just fetch inside using the useQuery hook to get the data only on that component

If you need to pass data around for a reasonable depth, use props. To some degrees, it's not "prop drilling", but just how React is meant to be used.
Where that gets too much, you just call the useQuery hook wherever you need it - it's cached, so it won't make another network request.
